# Error while decoding. The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters

Tags: asp.net, json

I am getting response from api in json format which is encoded I have stored json response in a table.I want to decode response and deserilize it.
When I am trying to decode the data ,getting error.

Error : The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

Actual Response in json :

```
data={"Id": "234", "Name": "pinky", "MobileNumber": "", "ClassName": "Class1_Physics",   "DOBTime": "1990-04-11 15:46:38", "Landline": "", "Status": "Unmarried"}
```

After Encoding :

data%3D%7B%22Id%22%3A%20%22234%22%2C%20%22Name%22%3A%20%22pinky%22%2C%20%22MobileNumber%22%3A%20%22%22%2C%20%22ClassName%22%3A%20%22Class1_Physics%22%2C%20%20%20%22DOBTime%22%3A%20%221990-04-11%2015%3A46%3A38%22%2C%20%22Landline%22%3A%20%22%22%2C%20%22Status%22%3A%20%22Unmarried%22%7D%0A

I have taken help of one of tool for decoding .
Code : 
// Fetching response which was stored in database and assigning to string called 'Name'

```
string base64Decoded, base64Decoded2;
                base64Decoded = Name.Trim();
            base64Decoded = base64Decoded.Replace('-', '+');
            base64Decoded = base64Decoded.Replace('_', '/');
            base64Decoded = base64Decoded.Replace('=', '/');
            base64Decoded = base64Decoded.Replace(':', '/');
            byte[] data2 = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64Decoded);
            base64Decoded2 = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data2);
```

Getting error at this line :

byte[] data2 = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64Decoded);

Comment: error lies in encoding. How are you encoding the string??

Comment: I have not done encoding.I am getting respone from one of vendor.

Comment: I don't see a base64 encoding anywhere there... I only see a url encoding...

Comment: @xanatos,is it url encoding?Thanks for ur comment.

Comment: @jui Try `string s2 = Uri.UnescapeDataString(s);`. You should obtain a string like `"data={"Id": "234", ...`

Comment: Thanks xanatos for ur help.I will do that now.

Comment: Great work.Your code work fine.Thanks a lot Xanatos.There are many record in my table.For few record I gave me '+' sign.Ex: data={"Id":+"454",+"Name":+"Neeta",+"MobileNumber":+""}

Comment: @xanatos,I used   string decodedUrl = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(base64Decoded); .This removed '+' also.